# Need help integrating a trigonometric function over an interval

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series, elliptic-integrals

I found an equation for calculating the perimeter of an ellipse and need help converting it to its series.

$$
\operatorname{p}\left(a,b\right) =
4a\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\,{1 − \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^{2} - b^{2}}}{a}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(θ\right)}\,\,}\,\,{\rm d}θ
$$
where
$$\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a} = \text{eccentricity (ellipse)}$$
therefore
$$a \geq b$$

So far, I have
$$
p(a,b) = 4a \cdot \biggl[\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{\biggl(1 − \bigl(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}\bigr)^2 \sin^2θ\biggr)^\frac{3}{2}}{-\bigl((\frac{1}{3} \bigl(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}\bigr)^3+C_2) \cdot (\frac{θ}{2} - \frac{sin(θ)}{4} + C_3)\bigr)} + C_1\biggr]_0^\frac{π}{2}
$$

I'm sure this naïve attempt has many mistakes, but I wanted to show that I've tried.  What is the correct way to integrate p (with respect to θ over 0 to π/2).

P.S. I hope my question is clear because I am new to MathJax and these equations took 20 minutes to compose. I am developing some software as a hobby to help with recursive and/or iterative calculations of unknown computational depth and/or iterations, respectively.  I currently have this working for calculating Fibonacci numbers, π, and other values of increasing complexity.  I think this calculation will most likely lead to an infinite series and not a tidy solution, but I am 20 years out of practice.

Comment: Why not just set $(a^2 - b^2)/a^2 = k$?  Can't you see through to the underlying problem?

Comment: Thank you, @RicardoCavalcanti.  I did not find that in my search results.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I didn't know for sure I could substitute (a^2 - b^2)/a^2 until after I either 1) relearned how to integrate a combination of trigonometric functions, exponents, products, and sums or 2) was shown an answer which uses substitution.  Even with substitution, I would not have been confident that my progress was in the right direction.  I could have probably done half of this integral in my head 20+ years ago, but I need community help now.

Answer (score 1):

Using elliptic integrals and your notations, we have for
$$p(a,b) = 4a \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} {\sqrt{1 − \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}\biggr)^2 \sin^2(θ)}}\,dθ$$
$$p(a,b)=4 aE\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)$$ Around $b=a$, you will get as series
$$p(a,b)=2\pi a \Big[1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\,x^n\Big]\qquad \text{with} \qquad x=\frac {a-b}a$$ the first coefficients being
$$\left\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{32},\frac{17}{1024},\frac{19}{2048},\frac
   {89}{16384},\frac{109}{32768},\frac{8921}{4194304},\frac{11887}{8388608},\cdots\right\}$$

Using these cofficients, the relative error is less tha $0.1$% as soon as $b>0.4 a$.

**Edit**

Let $k=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}$
$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \sqrt{1 − k^2 \sin^2(θ)}\,dθ=E\left(k^2\right)\quad \text{if} \quad \Im(k)\neq 0\lor -1\leq \Re(k)\leq 1$$ and, under these conditions,
$$E\left(k^2\right)=\frac \pi 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ [(2 n)!]^2 }{(1-2 n)\,2^{4n}\, (n!)^4} k^{2 n}$$ which is suitable for coding since
$$d_n=\frac{ [(2 n)!]^2 }{(1-2 n)\,2^{4n}\, (n!)^4}\implies d_{n+1}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n-1)}{4(n+1)^2}d_n$$ with $d_0=1$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had to finish work then process your answer. I have three issues with your answer:
1) how is it reasonable to assume this needs to work around $b = a$?  In fact, if $b$ does equal $a$, the answer is precisely $2πa$ (the circumference of a circle)
2) your answer includes $π$ in the solution which is technically another infinite series for the purposes of my calculations. I need the solution as one series, and
3) even if I must use $π$ (because of the nature of elliptic integrals), I would need the generic formula to calculate that series of coefficients.
Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMYoung. This is a Taylor series around $b=a$

Comment: @MarkMYoung. Have a look at my edit